# Call external API in wordpress based on user input

Tags: curl, http-api

I want to create a simple wordpress website in which I want to display a search box on a page. On searching a string in text/search box, an external API call should be made based on that string and the data returned by the API should be shown to user.
I have successfully referred code from below URL so far - https://rapidapi.com/blog/integrate-external-api-wordpress/.

But I am not able to make a call to API based on string passed in text box.
I have done below code so for in the child theme file page:-

```
<div id="primary" <?php generate_do_element_classes( 'content' ); ?>>
    <main id="main" <?php generate_do_element_classes( 'main' ); ?>>
        <form action="" method="post">
        Enter query:
        <input type=text name="t1">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type=submit name="s">
        <?php
        /**
         * generate_before_main_content hook.
         *
         * @since 0.1
         */
        do_action( 'generate_before_main_content' );

        if(isset($_POST['s'])){
        echo "good";    
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, [
            CURLOPT_URL => "******API URL*****/".$_POST['t1'],
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
                "x-rapidapi-host: XYZ",
                "x-rapidapi-key: ABc"
            ],
        ]);

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        if ($err) {
            echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
            echo $response;
        }
    }
                

        /**
         * generate_after_main_content hook.
         *
         * @since 0.1
         */
        do_action( 'generate_after_main_content' );
        ?>
        </form>
    </main>
</div>

<?php
/**
 * generate_after_primary_content_area hook.
 *
 * @since 2.0
 */
do_action( 'generate_after_primary_content_area' );

generate_construct_sidebars();

get_footer();
```

When I click on Submit button, it gives 'Page not Found'.

Comment: I would note that the tutorial you linked to has no escaping or sanitisation in the  output it recommends using. This would mean that if rapidapi was compromised, your site would be compromised too. If the API URL was not sufficiently secured, it could open the site to man in the middle attacks.

Comment: Thanks Tom, for highlighting this. I will study the above topics from wordpress documentation and implement in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s` is a reserved keyword, you cannot reuse the URL parameters and query variables used by WordPress itself. This issue is unrelated to the API request code.

Because your form has an input with the name `s`, the request is interpreted as a search request. As no posts were found in the WordPress search, you got a 404 response.

As a general rule of thumb, if a parameter is listed in the documentation as valid in a `WP_Query` post query object, it is unavailable for use in URLs.

Changing WordPress to allow `s` to be used would cripple a large portion of WordPress core functionality and require extensive internal modification of WordPress itself, as well as disabling all search related functionality, and any plugins that use similar systems, both on the frontend and in WP Admin.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed the keyword 's' with my own name and it worked. I have two more questions -1.  Is the above method good for API calling and returning of result or is there some better way also??   2. The above code is reloading the complete page on return of request, Can I use something similar to AJAX here, If yes is there any good resource to study the implementation of Ajax in wordpress child theme??

Comment: 1: Making the request in the browser via JS would be faster and reduce load on your server, but would mean your API keys woud be exposed so may not be feasible with that service

Comment: 2: You could use a REST API endpoint that takes a search parameter then makes the query and returns the data as JSON. Then your browser can query your server for the data without a reload, or even a mobile app, etc.

Comment: the details of how to do those though are for another question, and mostly involve javascript knowledge instead of WordPress knowledge once the API endpoint is operational

Comment: Okk. Thanks for the replies Tom.